# How to trim the object value and returned with new object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am tying to trim the values from a object, but not works.

```
var obj = {'name' : 'arif', 'city':'chennai'};

var y = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (obj, key) {
    return obj[key] = String(obj[key]).trim();
}, {});

console.log(y); //undefined
```

any one help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to iterate the object properties and update its values:

```js
var obj = {'name' : 'arif   ', 'city':'  chennai'};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = obj[k].trim());
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Don't use `map` like that - use `forEach` instead. `map` should be used for mutation, rather than iteration which is what you're doing here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the accumulator for the next iteration at the bottom of each callback, You should also use a different variable name for the object you're creating and the original `obj`, so that you can reference both separately:

```js
var obj = {'name' : 'arif   ', 'city':'chennai'};

var newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (newObj, key) {
    newObj[key] = obj[key].trim();
    return newObj;
}, {});

console.log(newObj);
```

Another option is to use `Object.fromEntries`, which looks significantly cleaner IMO (very modern environment or polyfill required):

```js
var obj = {'name' : 'arif   ', 'city':'chennai'};

var newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => [key, val.trim()])
);

console.log(newObj);
```